# Difference in SGD classifier results and statsmodels results for logistic with l1

Tags: scikit-learn, statsmodels

As a check on my work, I've been comparing the output of scikit learn's SGDClassifier logistic implementation with statsmodels logistic. Once I add some l1 in combination with categorical variables, I'm getting very different results. Is this a result of different solution techniques or am I not using the correct parameter?

Much bigger differences on my own dataset, but still pretty large using mtcars:

```
 df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets").data

 y, X = patsy.dmatrices('am~standardize(wt) + standardize(disp) + C(cyl) - 1', df)

 logit = sm.Logit(y, X).fit_regularized(alpha=.0035)

 clf = SGDClassifier(alpha=.0035, penalty='l1', loss='log', l1_ratio=1,
                n_iter=1000, fit_intercept=False)
 clf.fit(X, y)
```

gives:

```
sklearn: [-3.79663192 -1.16145654  0.95744308 -5.90284803 -0.67666106]
statsmodels: [-7.28440744 -2.53098894  3.33574042 -7.50604097 -3.15087396]
```

Comment: You could try changing the penalty weight alpha. It might not have the same normalization associated with it, and I doubt that they are defined or scaled in the same way, maybe related to the sample size. But I never checked.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working through some similar issues. I think the short answer might be that SGD doesn't work so well with only a few samples, but is (much more) performant with larger data. I'd be interested in hearing from sklearn devs. Compare, for example, using LogisticRegression

```
clf2 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=1/.0035, fit_intercept=False)
clf2.fit(X, y)
```

gives very similar to l1 penalized Logit.

```
array([[-7.27275526, -2.52638167,  3.32801895, -7.50119041, -3.14198402]])
```

Comment: Per user333700 suggestion, I tried different alpha's. They get pretty similar if you lower the SGDClassifier alpha down to .0001: `[-7.06883118 -2.51192083  3.45516038 -7.50767567 -3.06782151]`

Comment: Interesting. The loss function and penalty should be the same as far as I know. FWIW, if you look at the performance of the classifier with the original alpha, the predictions are the same though the coefficients aren't.

Comment: scikit-learn's SGD fits an unregularized intercept, while `LogisticRegression` regularizes its intercept (though not with the new solver by yours truly et al. that will be optional in the next release). At `n_iter=1000`, SGD should converge on most datasets.

Comment: So did we ever come up with a consensus on the differing results? SGD appears to have converged, at least in the sense that the result is the same on each run and is unchanged between 500 and 1000 iterations.