# Modelling probabilities in a regularized (logistic?) regression model in python

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I would like to fit a regression model to probabilities. I am aware that linear regression is often used for this purpose, but I have several probabilities at or near 0.0 and 1.0 and would like to fit a regression model where the output is constrained to lie between 0.0 and 1.0. I want to be able to specify a regularization norm and strength for the model and ideally do this in python (but an R implementation would be helpful as well). All the logistic regression packages I've found seem to be only suited for classification whereas this is a regression problem (albeit one where I want to use the logit link function). I use scikits-learn for my classification and regression needs so if this regression model can be implemented in scikits-learn, that would be fantastic (it seemed to me that this is not possible), but I'd be happy about any solution in python and/or R.

Comment: statsmodels has L1 regularized Logit, elastic net for GLM is in a pull request and will be merged soon. More penalized GLM like L2 penalization for GAM and splines will follow over the next months, based on pull requests that still need work.

Comment: scikit-learn also has logistic regression with both L1 and L2 penalization, AFAIK.

Comment: A question to clarify the data that you actually have: Is the dependent variable a probability/fraction/proportion (float in (0, 1)) or a binary variable? Binary and binomial models in statsmodels don't impose that the dependent variable is binary and works as long as it is in the [0,1] interval.

Comment: @user33700 Thanks! The dependent variable is a probability/fraction/proportion (float in (0, 1)), not a binary variable. Does that work with statsmodel? Can you point me to some example syntax?

Comment: One important question is how are the probabilities obtained? Are they from observed events? If they are you will often have different levels of confidence for the various probability estimates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246127/difference-in-sgd-classifier-results-and-statsmodels-results-for-logistic-with-l and https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/examples/l1_demo/short_demo.py  (penalization alpha can be a vector with zeros for coefficients like constant if they shouldn't be penalized.

Comment: @DavidMaust The probabilities are from observed events, but they are all based on the same number of observed events, so I wouldn't suspect that the confidence for the different probability estimates should vary much.

Comment: @user333700 does scikit-learn's logistic regression allow Y values in ]0, 1[ (i.e. interior of [0, 1])?

Comment: @Adrian scikit-learn didn't allow non-integers a while ago, but I don't know if that has changed in recent releases.

Comment: @user333700 I have scikit_learn-0.17.1-py3.4 and it doesn't allow non-integers in logistic regression.  statsmodels does, but it doesn't have l2 regularization (only l1).  I have essentially the same question as the OP:  I'd like to run logistic regression on fractional data (i.e. y in [0, 1]), with l2 regularization, in Python.

Comment: @Adrian elastic net is in https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2385

Answer (score 4):

The question has two issues, penalized estimation and fractional or proportions data as dependent variable. I worked on each separately but never tried the combination.

**Penalization**

Statsmodels has had L1 regularized Logit and other discrete models like Poisson for some time. In recent months there has been a lot of effort to support more penalization but it is not in statsmodels yet. Elastic net for linear and  Generalized Linear Model (GLM) is in a pull request and will be merged soon. More penalized GLM like L2 penalization for GAM and splines or SCAD penalization will follow over the next months based on pull requests that still need work.

Two examples for the current L1 fit_regularized for Logit are here
[Difference in SGD classifier results and statsmodels results for logistic with l1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246127/difference-in-sgd-classifier-results-and-statsmodels-results-for-logistic-with-l) and https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/examples/l1_demo/short_demo.py
Note, the penalization weight alpha can be a vector with zeros for coefficients like the constant if they should not be penalized.

http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.fit_regularized.html

**Fractional models**

Binary and binomial models in statsmodels do not impose that the dependent variable is binary and work as long as the dependent variable is in the [0,1] interval.

Fractions or proportions can be estimated with Logit as Quasi-maximum likelihood estimator. The estimates are consistent if the mean function, logistic, cumulative normal or similar link function, is correctly specified but we should use robust sandwich covariance for proper inference. Robust standard errors can be obtained in statsmodels through a fit keyword `cov_type='HC0'`.
Best documentation is for Stata http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rfracreg.pdf and the references therein. I went through those references before Stata had fracreg, and it works correctly with at least Logit and Probit which were my test cases. (I don't find my scripts or test cases right now.)

The bad news for inference is that robust covariance matrices have not been added to `fit_regularized`, so the correct sandwich covariance is not directly available. The standard covariance matrix and standard errors of the parameter estimates are derived under the assumption that the model, i.e. the likelihood function, is correctly specified, which will not be the case if the data are fractions and not binary.

Besides using Quasi-Maximum Likelihood with binary models, it is also possible to use a likelihood that is defined for fractional data in (0, 1). A popular model is Beta regression, which is also waiting in a pull request for statsmodels and is expected to be merged within the next months.

Comment: Thanks @user333700! So am I understanding you correctly that the combination of penalization and using proportions as dependent variable is not currently supported, but support is likely to be added to statsmodels, soon?

Comment: The estimation of the parameters and predicting the probabilities **should** work. (I never tried, but Logit has no code that requires abinary variable).  What is currently not implemented, but will be added, is to calculate the correct standard errors for the parameters and for the prediction.

Comment: Cool, thanks again @user333700 -- I will have a closer look at statsmodel. If anyone has example code that does that, I'd love to see it!

Comment: @user333700 Do you happen to know if Elastic Net has been implemented yet for logit models by now? If so, could you tell me how to use it?

Comment: Does sklearn support Logistic Regression using penalized estimation and fractional or proportions data as dependent variable yet?  I am looking all over and do not see this functionality.